# TimeStamp Convertion in mule esb

Tags: timestamp, mule, mule-el, date-conversion

I need to capture file last modified date in `yyyy-MM-dd format`.

I tried `#[message.inboundProperties.timestamp]` but getting timestamp like `142565954`.

Yes, I know it can be done using goovy or java.

Please can anybody suggest to convert the timestamp `142565954` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format with mule expression language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reference the below link:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-date-and-time-functions

Try something like this :

```
#[new org.mule.el.datetime.DateTime(new Date(message.inboundProperties.timestamp),"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,it worker for me with server.dateTime

```
#[message.inboundProperties.timestamp.format('yyyy-MM-dd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

That timestamp (message.inboundProperties.timestamp) is the message timestamp, not the file timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using within dataweave then please write as message.inboundProperties.timestamp as :date {format : "yyyy-MM-dd"}